# Posting to Web Api parameters are null

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a jquery method which looks like this:

```
$.post("/api/amazon/signature", { "policy": policy }, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

the api method looks like this~:

```
// POST api/amazon/signature
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/amazon/signature")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSignature([FromBody]string policy)
{
    var bKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"]);
    var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(bKey);

    var bPolicy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(policy);
    var hash = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(bPolicy);
    var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

    return Ok(encoded);
}
```

but when I run this code **policy** is always null!
If I change my method to this:

```
public class Signature
{
    public string Policy { get; set; }
}

// POST api/amazon/signature
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/amazon/signature")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSignature([FromBody]Signature model)
{
    var bKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"]);
    var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(bKey);

    var bPolicy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(model.Policy);
    var hash = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(bPolicy);
    var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

    return Ok(encoded);
}
```

and modify my jquery to this:

```
$.post("/api/amazon/signature", { "Policy": policy }, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

it works fine....

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API binds the request body in its entirety to one parameter (one parameter only and not more). By default, body is bound to a complex type. So, when you change the parameter type to `Policy` which is a complex type, you don't need to actually specify `FromBody`. Also binding works correctly now because you are sending JSON Object which looks something like this `{ "policy": policy }`. Web API has no trouble in binding JSON object to your complex type.

When it comes to a simple type, `string` in your case, you must specify `FromBody`, since by default Web API binds from URI path and query string. In that case however, you cannot send a JSON Object. Web API is going to bind the entire body to that parameter, which is `string`. So, the request body must be just a string like this - `"ABC123"` and not a JSON object. If you send just "ABC123" (including the quotes) in the request body, your `string` parameter will be populated with ABC123.